# Windows 10 doesn't accept my password during system recovery

Tags: windows-10, passwords, system-restore, system-recovery

I made a system image of my laptop. I want to restore my system to the state of that image. I followed the procedure described online on many places (i.e. advanced restart --> trouble shoot --> advanced options --> system image recovery/or any other option).

I then select my user name from the list of operating systems. Then I am asked to enter a password. My password is however not accepted.

This is the point where I am stuck. It won't accept my password and it is definitely correct (correct keyboard settings too/only English letter anyway).

I've read online that I'm not the only one who has run into this, but nowhere a real solution is offered.

Does anyone know how I can restore my system image (on external hard drive) another way? Or perhaps how I can make windows accept my password?

I am genuinely hopeless at this point.

---

As an alternative, would it be wise to simply drag and drop the copy of my old C-drive onto "This PC" thereby overwriting the current C-drive?

**Edit:** I read someone suggesting I activate the hidden admin account and from that account execute `REAGENTC /BOOTTORE`. Next restart and Windows should not ask for a password. Sadly it still does, so this does not work.

Comment: does your account have local administrator rights? Is it a windows-live account?

Comment: My laptop has only one account (so must be admin right?). Not a windows-live account

Comment: @gebruiker - You should enable the built-in Administrator, and verify, if your account is an Administrator.  Local accounts are not typically an Administrator, and since your not sure it is, it likely isn’t

Comment: What password did you enter? Try the password you created when backing up the image.

Comment: @DaisyZhou My password is Always the same (not very safe I know). So that password is the same as the one I entered.

Comment: "would it be wise to simply drag and drop the copy of my old C-drive onto "This PC" thereby overwriting the current C-drive?" -  **This would break your current installation.**

Comment: @Ramhound The current installation is a factory reset. Would it restore my old installation?

Comment: @gebruiker - Would What restore your installation?  Dragging and dropping files will break your installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot from Windows 10 installation DVD, and click "Repair your computer". Navigate to advanced restart --> troubleshoot --> advanced options --> system image recovery, and it should not prompt you to enter any password.

Comment: but it does ask me for a password

Comment: This did work for me - it did not ask me for a password. Just make sure when you boot you are booting from the DVD/USB media you created. In my case it was a VM so I booted from the ISO.